# Is this the right way that i can parseInt inside if else statement for Datatable

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, datatables

I am new to JS BS Datatables, is this the right way to parseInt for if else statement?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTable').DataTable({
        "order": [],
        "columnDefs": [{
            "targets": 'nosort',
            "orderable": false,
        }],
        
        
        "fnRowCallback": function(nRow, aData) {
            if (parseInt(aData[7].innerHTML,10) <= 30) {
                $('td', nRow).css('background-color', 'Red');
            } else if (aData[2] >= "30" && aData[2] < "50") {
                $('td', nRow).css('background-color', 'Green');
            }
        }
    });

});
```

for example as you can see from my code i try to convert the row aData[7] to intiger and put into statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  "fnRowCallback": function(nRow, aData) {
                if (parseInt(aData[7], 10) <= 30) {
                    $('td', nRow).css('background-color', 'Red');
                } else if (parseInt(aData[7], 10) >= 31 && parseInt(aData[7], 10) <= 50) {
                    $('td', nRow).css('background-color', 'orange');
                }
            } else if (parseInt(aData[7], 10) >= 31 && parseInt(aData[7], 10) <= 50) {
                $('td', nRow).css('background-color', 'orange');
            }
```

Hi everyone sorry for the question, I already solve it.